# Probability, balls from bag

Tags: probability

There are $10$ black balls and $15$ white balls in a bag, choosing $6$ at random, not replacing them after taking them out.

Chances that
A) All $6$ are black

I've been able to figure this one out pretty easily. Ends up being $.00119$
(Not sure how to actually write the "probability" I havent done this stuff since year $11$, ($4$ years ago) and have completely forgotten.

B) All $6$ are white

As above, i've figured it out to be $0.0283$

C) $3$ White $3$ Black.

I cant for the life of me figure this out. Unless its as simple as

$10/25 * 9/24 * 8/23 * 15/22 * 14/21 * 13/20$ But that just seems silly.

Comment: The value you have written ($\frac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 15\cdot 14\cdot 13}{25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21\cdot 20}$) is the probability that the first three balls are black and the final three balls are white where order matters.  But, it need not only have been BBBWWW, it could also have been BBWBWW and BWBBWW and any other arrangement of blacks and whites.  Correct your count by realizing there are $\binom{6}{3}=\frac{6!}{3!3!}=20$ ways to arrange three B's and three W's and in each of those arrangements the probability is as above.  Multiplying your answer by $20$ corrects it then.

Answer (score 4):

The number of ways of choosing any $6$ out of $25$ is $\binom{25}{6}$.

This is your denominator.

$A)$ Number of ways of choosing $6$ blacks out of $10$ is $\binom{10}{6}$
and the probability is

$$P_A = \frac{\binom{10}{6}}{\binom{25}{6}}$$

$B)$ Number of ways of choosing $6$ whites out of $15$ is $\binom{15}{6}$

$$P_B = \frac{\binom{15}{5}}{\binom{25}{6}}$$

$C)$ Number of ways of choosing $3$ blacks out of $10$ and $3$ whites out of $15 $ is $\binom{10}{3} \cdot \binom{15}{3}$

$$P_C = \frac{\binom{10}{3} \cdot \binom{15}{3}}{\binom{25}{6}}$$

Answer (score 3):

**C:**

You started right, you found the probability of getting $BBBWWW$

But there could be $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$ different sequences in which three blacks and three whites could occur.

If you multiply your attempt by this multiplying factor, you'll get the correct result.

---

**Guide for future**

For problems of drawing without replacement, the prferrable method to use is:

**combinations**, when order is not specified:
e.g. for this problem, $\frac{\binom{10}3\binom{15}3}{\binom{25}{6}}$

**multiplying probabilities**, when order is specified,
e.g. if the order is specified as $BBWBWW$, then $\frac{15}{25}\frac{14}{24}\frac{10}{23}\frac{13}{22}\frac{9}{21}\frac{8}{20}$

If you use the "other" method instead, you have a good chance of forgetting that a multiplication/division factor is needed for a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of drawing 3 black balls and 3 white balls is
$$ \frac{{10\choose 3}{15\choose 3}}{{25\choose 6}}\approx 0.3083 $$
where ${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is a binomial coefficient, which counts the number of ways to choose $k$ objects out of $n$. This problem is an example of the so-called hypergeometric distribution.